# How to pass data from two columns to popup label for markers for choropleth map made using folium?

Tags: pandas, markers, folium

[image: enter link description here]

I would like each popup to have the name of the bar and position on the WB100 list, columns: Bar, wb_pos. This is my code, some reason each marker's popup is the same = "Tokyo" Please see dataframe and output attached.

Please see part of the dataframe below:

```py
data = {'Bar': {0: 'Connaught Bar', 1: 'Dante', 2: 'The Clumsies', 3: 'Atlas', 4: 'Tayēr + Elementary'}, 'City': {0: 'London', 1: 'New York', 2: 'Athens', 3: 'Singapore', 4: 'London'}, 'Country': {0: 'UK', 1: 'USA', 2: 'Greece', 3: 'Singapore', 4: 'UK'}, 'Delivery': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}, 'Latitude': {0: 51.507351, 1: 40.7128, 2: 37.9838, 3: 1.3521, 4: 23.7275}, 'Longitude': {0: 0.1278, 1: 74.006, 2: 23.7275, 3: 103.8198, 4: 0.1278}, 'Region': {0: 'Europe', 1: 'North America', 2: 'Europe', 3: 'Asia', 4: 'Europe'}, 'Shop': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1}, 'Takeway': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1}, 'Virtual Events': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'first_submission': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'wb_pos': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}}
dfcv = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import folium 
import branca
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

world_geo = r'world_countries.json' # geojson file

world_map=folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=3, width=1100, height=800, tiles='cartodb positron', max_bounds=True)
world_map.choropleth( 
    name='choropleth WB100', 
    geo_data=world_geo, 
    data=dfcv, 
    columns=['Country', 'Total'], 
    key_on='feature.properties.name', 
    nan_fill_color='white', 
    nan_fill_opacity=0.1, 
    fill_color='Blues', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
legend_name='Worlds Best 100 Bars'
)

world_map

mapa = folium.map.FeatureGroup()
# loop through the WB100 and add each Bar location, name and WB100 position
for lat, lng, bar, pos in zip(df.Latitude, 
                          df.Longitude, 
                          df.Bar,
                          df.wb_pos):
    mapa.add_child(
        folium.CircleMarker(
            [lat,lng],
            label='{}, {}'.format(bar, pos),
            popup=label,
            radius=5, # define how big you want the circle markers to be
            color='yellow',
            fill=True,
            fill_color='blue',
            fill_opacity=0.6
        ).add_to(mapa)
    )
world_map.add_child(mapa)
```

[image: This is my output]

Comment: `NameError: name 'dfcv' is not defined` -> what exactly is dfcv?

Comment: Also, you do not have a `Total` field in your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some mistakes in your code, here's a working example based on the 'wb_pos' field of your input data because you actually do not have any `Total` field.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(df) # Needed to convert your dict to an actual DataFrame

world_geo = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdamiani27/Data-Visualization-and-D3/master/lesson4/world_countries.json' # geojson file

world_map = folium.Map(
    location = [0, 0],
    zoom_start = 3,
    width = 1100,
    height = 800,
    tiles = 'cartodb positron',
    max_bounds = True
)
world_map.choropleth( 
    name = 'choropleth WB100', 
    geo_data = world_geo, 
    data = df, # Replaced dfcv because it was not defined in your input data
    columns = ['Country', 'wb_pos'], # Replaced the 'Total' by another random column, here 'wb_pos'
    key_on = 'feature.properties.name',  
    nan_fill_color = 'white', 
    nan_fill_opacity = 0.1, 
    fill_color = 'Blues', 
    fill_opacity = 0.7, 
    line_opacity = 0.2,
    legend_name = 'Worlds Best 100 Bars'
)

world_map

mapa = folium.map.FeatureGroup()
# loop through the WB100 and add each Bar location, name and WB100 position
for lat, lng, bar, pos in zip(
    df.Latitude, 
    df.Longitude, 
    df.Bar,
    df.wb_pos):
    
    label= '{}, {}'.format(bar, pos) # Define label here to reuse after
    
    mapa.add_child(
        folium.CircleMarker(
            [lat,lng],
            label = label,
            popup = label,
            radius = 5, # define how big you want the circle markers to be
            color = 'yellow',
            fill = True,
            fill_color = 'blue',
            fill_opacity = 0.6
        ).add_to(mapa)
    )

# Build a CircleMarker for each row based on the lat long of the record
df.apply(lambda row: folium.CircleMarker(
    location=[row["Latitude"],
    row["Longitude"]],
    radius=10,).add_to(world_map), axis=1)

world_map.add_child(mapa)
```

I also had to fix your `label` which raised an error because you cannot reuse a parameter in the same list of parameters when they are passed to a function, you need to define it *before*.

And here is the corresponding result:

[image: Resulting map]
*Figure will be fixed when the 'Total' field will be available.*

Please, also notice the existence of https://gis.stackexchange.com/ for all questions with a geographical nature.

Comment: thank you so much! @s.k This is my very first project, clearly made quite a few mistakes here, again thanks for your help.